# Space between conclusion and appendices in ToC

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to add some space between conclusion chapter and the first appendix in ToC. I'm already using **\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}** to adjust vertical length of the space between ALL chapters in ToC. My code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %changing vertical length of the space between ALL chapters
                             %entries in ToC via \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6pt} 
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}

\chapter{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}
\chapter{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}
\section{4444444}
\section{5555555}
\section{6666666}
\chapter{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclu}


\appendix
\chapter{aaaaaaa}
\chapter{bbbbbbbb}
\chapter{ccccccccc}

\end{document}
```

And the picture to make things more clear,

[image]

Cheers!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vskip<length>}
```

with the desired value for `<length>`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} %changing vertical length of the space between ALL chapters
                             %entries in ToC via \setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{1pt}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{6pt} 
\tableofcontents


\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Intro}

\chapter{aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}
\chapter{bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}
\section{4444444}
\section{5555555}
\section{6666666}
\chapter{ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc}
\section{111111}
\section{222222}
\section{3333333}

\chapter*{Conclusion}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Conclu}

\appendix
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\vskip30pt}
\chapter{aaaaaaa}
\chapter{bbbbbbbb}
\chapter{ccccccccc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\addtocontents` line has to be placed *before* the `\chapter` line of the first chapter in the appendices; if you use `\include` to pull the chapters together, the `\addtocontents` instruction has to go into the chapter file, just before the `\chapter` line; otherwise, the added space might result in the wrong place.

Comment: if the author is actually using `\include` to pull the chapters together, the `\addtocontents` instruction has to go into the chapter file, just before the `\chapter` line.  the `\include` mechanism manages to delay an `\add...` line otherwise, so it will take effect *after* that chapter file is preocessed.  (always a surprise!)

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, you're right. I've added this remark to my edited answer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton fixed.