# Space between parts and indices in KOMA script (in the TOC)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\part{A}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}

\part{B}
\chapter{First}
\chapter{Second}
\chapter{Third}

\appendix

\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

As expected, there is a lot of space between Introduction and Part I, as Introduction does not belong to Part I.

However, there is little space between Part II and the Appendix, even though Appendix does not belong to Part II.

Is it possible to make the space between Part II and Appendix as large as the space between Introduction and Part I?

I know I can do this manually [Space between conclusion and appendices in ToC](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/156271/space-between-conclusion-and-appendices-in-toc), but I need to guess the correct spacing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of an appendix chapter use a appendix part. I added blindtext, because I got (in other examples) strange results with lists of chapters. However:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext{}
\part{A}
\chapter{First}
\blindtext{}
\chapter{Second}
\blindtext{}
\chapter{Third}
\blindtext{}

\part{B}
\chapter{First}
\blindtext{}
\chapter{Second}
\blindtext{}
\chapter{Third}
\blindtext{}

\appendix

\part{\appendixname}
% \chapter{Appendix}

\blindtext{}

\blindtext{}
\end{document}
```

[image: pic of toc]

Comment: I do **not** want Appendix part.  This is just a sample problem, I have actually several chapters after Part II.

Comment: @Pygmalion Readers can't come and ask you about the reasons for an inconsistent structure in your book. If you use parts, every chapter has to belong to a part. But this isn't an issue of LaTex.

Comment: IMHO, frontmatter and appendices are common to all parts, so should not be contained by a particular part.  I doubt this structure breaks some rule book styling rule, but if it does, I am prepared to change it and turn frontmatter and appendices into parts.